# RoR: reloading initializers for delayed_job :perfomable classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous, delayed-job

While using delayed_job module in RoR, I confronted with the next problem:
My booted RoR app has one context while my :perfomable classes(delayed tasks) in /lib dir has another context: initializers loaded two times. So it means, that I couldn't use shared constants stored in initializers, because one constant created two times. 
What could you advise me ?

I would like to use constants to store some data on application level, rather than - on persistence level.

Answer (score 0):

You could use in memory shared store, for example [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Comment: Thank you. I like your suggestion. But for now, I just patched delayed_job backend. Now it allows me to store additional parameters 'extra', retrieve jobs by those parameters and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I advice everybody to use Resque or Rabbit for system tasks. Delayed job is not good because it loads new rails context for each task.